# How to Deploy Azure Function App via Azure CLI?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cli, azure-functions-docker

I have an Azure Function App Written in C# and I am trying to build them using the "docker build" command on my local machine. The build is getting completed successfully. Now I have a Docker Image on my local machine which I would like to try Deploying to Azure for testing purposes. Can this be done?

I have attempted to do it via Azure CLI, but I am not sure of ways to point to my Local Docker Image. What is the recommended way?

```
az functionapp deployment container config --enable-cd true --name function-app-name --resource-group resource_group_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you need to push your custom docker image into `Azure Container Registry`, and then configure the Azure App Service to deploy the image from registry.

and Yes - you can't deploy to Azure function Apps (FaaS) since custom image is considered platform as service (PaaS)

[Build and run a custom container in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-custom-container?pivots=container-linux)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, This Feature is not available right now.

The [**MS Doc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push) says that **.zip file deployment** uses the same Kudu service that powers ***continuous integration-based deployments***, it includes the **Syncing function triggers in a `Consumption plan` function app.**.

If you are using a **Linux Container** it requires the **Premium plan** or a **Dedicated (App Service) plan**. The Azure function with **Windows Container** is not supported. Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/172659/function-windows-container.html).

You can refer [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=in-process,bash,azure-cli&pivots=programming-language-csharp) to create Azure function in the container.